# discord.js How do you make a reaction collector

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make it so when you get to a certain amount of reactions my bot will send a message and if somebody can help here is my code

```
.then(function(sentMessage) {
            sentMessage.react('').catch(() => console.error('emoji failed to react.')).message.reactions.cache.get('').count;
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 2, time: 00, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
    .catch(collected => {
        console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
    });
        });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`awaitReactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions), you could also use [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) which is probably easier to use and its `collector.on()` listeners are more readable than `awaitReactions`'s `then()` and `catch()` methods.

You won't need to use `message.reactions.cache.get('').count` to check the number of reactions, as the `end` event fires when you reached the maximum and you can send a message inside that.

Also, in your `filter`, you don't need to check if `user.id === message.author.id` as you will want to accept reactions from other users. However, you can check if `!user.bot` to make sure that you won't count the bot's reaction. You can also remove the `time` option if you don't want to limit the time your bot collects reactions.

Another error was that you called `.awaitReactions()` on the `message` itself not the `sentMessage`.

Check out the working code below:

```js
// v12
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const MAX_REACTIONS = 2;

  if (command === 'react') {
    try {
      // send a message and wait for it to be sent
      const sentMessage = await message.channel.send('React to this!');

      // react to the sent message
      await sentMessage.react('');

      // set up a filter to only collect reactions with the  emoji
      // and don't count the bot's reaction
      const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot;

      // set up the collecrtor with the MAX_REACTIONS
      const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
        max: MAX_REACTIONS,
      });

      collector.on('collect', (reaction) => {
        // in case you want to do something when someone reacts with 
        console.log(`Collected a new ${reaction.emoji.name} reaction`);
      });

      // fires when the time limit or the max is reached
      collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
        // reactions are no longer collected
        // if the  emoji is clicked the MAX_REACTIONS times
        if (reason === 'limit')
          return message.channel.send(`We've just reached the maximum of ${MAX_REACTIONS} reactions.`);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // "handle" errors
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

If you're using discord.js v13, there are a couple of changes:

- you'll need to add the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intents
- the `message` event is now `messageCreate`
- the collector's `filter` is inside the `options` object

```js
// v13
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
  ],
});
const prefix = '!';

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const MAX_REACTIONS = 2;

  if (command === 'react') {
    try {
      // send a message and wait for it to be sent
      const sentMessage = await message.channel.send('React to this!');

      // react to the sent message
      await sentMessage.react('');

      // set up a filter to only collect reactions with the  emoji
      // and don't count the bot's reaction
      const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot;

      // set up the collecrtor with the MAX_REACTIONS
      const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector({
        filter,
        max: MAX_REACTIONS,
      });

      collector.on('collect', (reaction) => {
        // in case you want to do something when someone reacts with 
        console.log(`Collected a new ${reaction.emoji.name} reaction`);
      });

      // fires when the time limit or the max is reached
      collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
        // reactions are no longer collected
        // if the  emoji is clicked the MAX_REACTIONS times
        if (reason === 'limit')
          return message.channel.send(`We've just reached the maximum of ${MAX_REACTIONS} reactions.`);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // "handle" errors
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the `collected.size` with an `if` statement like so:

```js
let amount = 4; // any integer
if (collected.size /* returns an integer */ === amount) {
console.log(`Got ${amount} reactions`)
}
```

Hope I got the issue right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, then you can just change the parameters for the `awaitMessage` method. You can remove the `time: 00, errors: ['time']` arguments since they're optional and keep the `max: 2`. That way, the function will only finish once there are `2` reactions (in this case).

I would recommend removing the `user.id === message.author.id;` from the filter since it seems like you want multiple users to react to the message.

For more information, you can check the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions) or the [documentation for awaitReactions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions).

Code:

```js
message.channel.send("Message reacting to.").then(function (sentMessage) {
    sentMessage.react('').catch(() => console.error('emoji failed to react.'));
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === '';
    };
    message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 2 })
        .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
});
```