# Discord reactions collector doesn't collect reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've read up on the discord.js documentation and have been trying such things that I've been reading but none of them seems to work. The main issue that I am having is that the collector is stating that it has collected nothing.

```js
if (message.content === 'poll') {
  let embedPoll = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(' DaSquad ')
    .setColor('YELLOW')
    .addField('1:', 'name')
    .addField('2:', 'name2')
    .addField('3:', 'name3')
    .addField('4:', 'name4')
    .addField('5:', 'name5')
    .addField('6:', 'name6')
    .addField('7:', 'name7')
    .addField('8:', 'name8');
  let msgEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embedPoll] });
  await msgEmbed.react('1️⃣');
  await msgEmbed.react('2️⃣');
  await msgEmbed.react('3️⃣');
  await msgEmbed.react('4️⃣');
  await msgEmbed.react('5️⃣');
  await msgEmbed.react('6️⃣');
  await msgEmbed.react('7️⃣');
  await msgEmbed.react('8️⃣');

  const filter = (reaction) =>
    reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣' ||
    reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣' ||
    reaction.emoji.name === '3️⃣' ||
    reaction.emoji.name === '4️⃣' ||
    reaction.emoji.name === '5️⃣' ||
    reaction.emoji.name === '6️⃣' ||
    reaction.emoji.name === '7️⃣' ||
    reaction.emoji.name === '8️⃣';

  const collector = new Discord.ReactionCollector(msgEmbed, filter);

  console.log(collector.collected);
}
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: v14.16.1 @ZsoltMeszaros

Comment: It sounds like that's the version of your node.js.

Comment: Sorry about that the verison is discord.js@13.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `ReactionCollector` class, you could use either `awaitReactions` or `createReactionCollector` that's available on the message object you've sent (`msgEmbed`).

If you're using discord.js v13, the [`awaitReactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) and [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) methods accept a single parameter and the `filter` is part of the `options` object now. (See [Changes in v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#collectors).) So, you need to update that; pass down a single object with the `filter`.

Another error is that you try to read the collected reactions (`collector.collected`) with a simple `console.log` right after you instantiated the collector. You should instead set up event listeners and subscribe to the `collect` (and probably `stop`) events.

Make sure you add the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intents. You can read [more about reaction collectors here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543726/discord-js-how-do-you-make-a-reaction-collector/67550715#67550715).

And one more thing, you could create an array with all the emojis you want to react with to make your life a bit easier.

Check out the code below:

```js
if (message.content === 'poll') {
  let embedPoll = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(' DaSquad ')
    .setColor('YELLOW')
    .addField('1:', 'name')
    .addField('2:', 'name2')
    .addField('3:', 'name3')
    .addField('4:', 'name4')
    .addField('5:', 'name5')
    .addField('6:', 'name6')
    .addField('7:', 'name7')
    .addField('8:', 'name8');

  let reactions = ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣', '6️⃣', '7️⃣', '8️⃣'];
  let msgEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embedPoll] });

  reactions.forEach((reaction) => msgEmbed.react(reaction));

  const filter = (reaction) => reactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name);
  const collector = msgEmbed.createReactionCollector({ filter });

  // code inside this runs every time someone reacts with those emojis
  collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Just collected a ${reaction.emoji.name} reaction from ${user.username}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: So I've tried the code that you send over, but it still seems like there is nothing being collected as nothing shows up in the console

Comment: Probably missing the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intents? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543726/discord-js-how-do-you-make-a-reaction-collector/67550715#67550715